# C# not writing values to the registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm currently developing a C# application which will record registry changes, save them to a file, then later be able to write the preferences saved to the file back to the registry.

So far I can get all the way through the process till I try and write the values back to the file. The code runs through with no errors, but when I look in the registry the values I've changed haven't changed and when I've tried to create new values they haven't been created so I need a hand.

Just for further information I'm creating and testing the application in Windows XP SP3.

Just to show you what I'm doing, heres 2 examples. The one below I've used just to create some new subkeys and values and at no point do any appear in regedit:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test9999");

            using (RegistryKey testName = rk.CreateSubKey("TestName"), testSettings = rk.CreateSubKey("TestSettings"))
            {
                // Create data for the TestSettings subkey.
                testSettings.SetValue("Language", "French");
                testSettings.SetValue("Level", "Intermediate");
                testSettings.SetValue("ID", 123);
            }
```

This second example shows the key that I really want to work on, what I'm testing here is whether it creates a new value test, enters the value held by the testing string and set it as the correct value kind. The real value I want to change is 01020402 in the same key which changes whether outlooks reading pane is at the right or bottom of the screen, but I thought it would be best to test first:

```
Registry.Users.SetValue("S-1-5-21-2055990625-1247778217-514451997-41655\\\\Software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows NT\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Windows Messaging Subsystem\\\\Profiles\\\\Outlook\\\\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046\\\\test", testing, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

In the above example no new value is created or stored.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong or give me any help it would  be appreciated.

Comment: Just tested your first code block and it works fine. Are you sure you're refreshing RegEdit after you've run the code?

Comment: Yep hitting F5 to refresh and closing/opening it to check and still nothing, also tried your Flush() and Close() suggestion

Comment: Are you looking in the right place? I.e. your first block uses CurrentUser and your second block uses Users? Just clutching at straws because it all works for me.

Comment: Yep checking in the right place, am only trying to get the first block working at the moment, so I'm only checking CURRENT_USER area of the hive although I have also checked USERS. Also I've got the correct permissions as the program is running using my credentials and I'm a system admin.

Comment: Last question - have you stepped through the code to make sure it's actually executing...?

Comment: Yes doing it line by line as it writes to the registry when the application initizlizes so its the first thing it does.

Comment: Good luck! Sorry I cant be more help.

Comment: Well I've now found the issue, its because I'm a new starter/guinea pig and I've been using a virtual implementation of visual studio 2008. Anyway this virtual implementation wouldn't let me write registry keys or values, but when I built the project and ran it, it created them fine.

So if you want the rep points make any answer you like and I'll give you them as your help was very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a false alarm due to running Visual Studio 2008 as a virtual application as a guinea pig for one of my work colleagues.

Thanks for the help.